# R lengend 'topright' not working in parmfrow=c(1,2) setting

Tags: r, legend

Here is the expample to reproduce my problem:

```
s=1:23400/23400
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(s,exp(-s),type='l')
legend('topright',legend=c('Ml','M_gaussian','true'),
       col=c('red','blue','black'),lty=c(1,1,1),cex=1,bty ='n')
plot(s,exp(-s),type='l')
legend('topright',legend=c('Ml','M_gaussian','true'),
       col=c('red','blue','black'),lty=c(1,1,1),cex=1,bty ='n')
```

Output:
[image]
Observe that the legends are not posited in the topright, and what I want is something like:
[image]
So what's wrong in my codes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` instead of `parmfrow=c(1,2)` ?

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, sorry and I have fixed it. I run the code in another computer with larger display, and it works well. So is the display screen  too small?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just tried it over here with the default window size and it seemed to work okay.

Comment: Works fine for me (win and lnx), perhaps either close your graphic device (with `dev.off()` for the appropriate device(s)) or restart R.